# Is there an equivalent to /dev/null in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, unix, batch, redirection

If I want to ignore `stdout` of a command, I do this on *nix:

```
myprog > /dev/null
```

How do I achieve the same on Windows (in `cmd` or a batch file)?

Comment: See also on stackoverflow: [How to redirect stderr to null in cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312)

Comment: [How to suppress windows command output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11463544/995714)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `NUL`:

```
myprog > NUL
```

Answer (score -1):

Just tried myprog > NUL on my Windows console, doesn't work.
Should be myprog>NUL (no space characters) e.g. npm i>NUL works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works for me, with or without spaces.